# Which version of SQL Server 2016 supports R

Tags: sql-server, statistics, sql-server-2016, r-language

Microsoft buying REvolution results (amongst other things) in the [integration of R in SQL Server 2016](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/05/r-in-sql-server.html).

Looking through the [features supported by the SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#SSAS) I cannot find R-Support. Does anyone know to what feature R-Integration belongs to or what version(s) integrate this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2.2](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)  is the latest release of SQL Server 2016. This version **does not have** **`R`** support.

Later release of 2016 *(probably 3.0)* will have support for **`R`** language.

> Found [this slideshare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/idigdata/sql-server-2016-ctp-technical-deep-dive) (slide - 130) that says `R` support will be in CTP 3.0.

---

EDIT: Announced and demoed in PASS Summit 2015 - As of SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.0, [SQL server supports **Advanced Analytics (RRE integration)**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/10/28/sql-server-2016-community-technology-preview-3-0-is-available.aspx):

> With this release, we are very excited to announce the public availability SQL Server R Services in SQL Server 2016, an Advanced Analytics capability which supports enterprise-scale data science, significantly reducing the friction for adopting machine learning in your business. SQL Server R Services is all about helping customers embrace the highly popular open source R language in their business. R is the most popular programming language for Advanced Analytics. You can use it to analyze data, uncover patterns and trends and build predictive models. It offers an incredibly rich set of packages and a vibrant and fast-growing developer community. At the same time, embracing R in an enterprise setting presents certain challenges, especially as the volume of data rises and with the switch from modeling to production environments. Microsoft SQL Server R Services with in-database analytics helps customers embrace this technology by supporting several scenarios.

Also, Henk blogs about [Introducing Microsoft SQL Server 2016 R Services](http://henkvandervalk.com/introducing-microsoft-sql-server-2016-r-services)

Comment: Do you know if the Standard or Express Edition will support R language?

Comment: @ruedi I would doubt that, since majority of new features are released as Enterprise ONLY features. This is my assumption ONLY.

Comment: Should be all editions, like JSON etc., but quite frankly, nobody here will actually be able to answer that question because those decisions are very rarely made this early (and even if they are, they aren't made public). (@Kin they are getting much better about making core features available in all editions, especially since this is better for them in compatibility with Azure SQL Database.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking about the editions of SQL Server 2016 supporting R Services (R integration), I believe that basic R integration is supported by pretty much all editions. Advanced R integration is only supported by **Enterprise** and **Developer** Editions.

Here's more detailed information by Microsoft that might help:

- Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

  Please scroll down to *'Programmability'* to find a grid for R Services Support.
- Differences in R Features between Editions of SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt721284.aspx

Comment: Here's some more information regarding SQL Server 2016 editions with R Services Support - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt721284.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the installation center for SQL server 2016 you have two options: Standalone R server and built-in.

So far I have successfully tested built-in option on Developer edition. It allows you to run R script from SSMS after you enable it.

Answer (score -1):

You should not focus on building too many tightly coupled solution, you should be focussing more on the aspects of building an ETL pipeline which uses, SQL Server as a source and later allows you to plug custom R scripts for any statistical use cases. Here you can think of using SSIS, or even KNIME for open source offerings.